# Trigger Javascript Validation then ASP.NET Control Submit_Click1

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to trigger a very basic Javascript validation followed by running the ASP.NET control that is behind it. I was hoping that OnClientClick followed by OnClick would work, but I have not been able to have it work properly.

Below is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DownloadLP.aspx.cs" Inherits="DownloadLP" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript"> 
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });

</script>

<script>
    function validateForm(){
        var fname = document.forms["form2"]["FName"].value;
        var lname = document.forms["form2"]["LName"].value;
        var email = document.forms["form2"]["CustEmail"].value;

        if(fname == ""){
            document.getElementsByClassName('error')[0].innerHTML = "Please provide your first name"
        }else{
            document.getElementsByClassName('error')[0].innerHTML = ""
        }
        if(lname == ""){
            document.getElementsByClassName('error')[1].innerHTML = "Please provide your last name"
        }else{
            document.getElementsByClassName('error')[1].innerHTML = ""
        }
        if(email == ""){
            document.getElementsByClassName('error')[2].innerHTML = "Please provide your first name"
        }else{
            document.getElementsByClassName('error')[2].innerHTML = ""
        }
        if (fname == "" || lname == "" || email == "") {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
     .navbar-new-top {
        background: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        font-weight: 600;
    }

        .navbar-brand img {
            width: 20%;
        }

    .navbar-new-top ul {
        margin-right: 9%;
    }

        .navbar-new-top ul li {
            margin-right: 8%;
        }

    .navbar-new-bottom {
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        margin-top: 4%;
        height: 40px;
    }

        .navbar-new-bottom ul li {
            margin-left: 2%;
            margin-right: 2%;
        }

    .navbar-nav .nav-item a {
        color: #333;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
        transition: 1s ease;
    }

        .navbar-nav .nav-item a:hover {
            color: #0062cc;
        }

    .dropdown-menu.show {
        background: #f8f9fa;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    .header-btn {
        width: 161%;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        padding: 8%;
        background: #0062cc;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 13px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .padDiv {
        min-height: 62px !important;
    }

    .input-group-addon {
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1;
        color: #555555;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    .input-group-btn {
        width: 1%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .input-group-addon .input-group .form-control {
        display: table-cell;
    }

    .container-register{
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
    }

    #npRegistration {
        background-color: gainsboro;
        padding-left: 40px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        border-style: solid;
        max-width: 960px;
    }

    .btnRegister {
        /*margin-top: 20px;*/
        background-color: #d8842c;
    }

    .register-begin {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .info-form {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .tooltip-inner {
        max-width: 350px;
        width: 350px; 
        background-color: #28a745;
     }

    .tooltip-inner ul {
        list-style:none;
        text-align:left;
     }
     
     .container-section {
        max-width: 1000px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 30px auto;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
     .section-image{
        max-width: 25%;
        background:rgb(255,255,255);
        border-radius: 50%;
        
    }
     .section-box{
        max-width:50%;
        max-height:auto;
    
    }
     .socialmedia {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #000000;
        margin-top: 20px;
        line-height: 85px;
        color: #fff;
        margin:10px;
    }
     .logo{
        height:50px; 
        display:block;
      }
     .checkBullet{
        padding:2%;
        margin-left:25%
     }

@media screen and (max-width:600px){
.logo{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    height:50px;
}
.checkBullet{
    padding:2%;
    margin-left:20%
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:375px){
.logo{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    height:30px;
}
.checkBullet{
    padding:2%;
    margin-left:10%
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 register-begin"> 
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="images/new-logo.png" style="height:50px" />"
</div>

    <div class="container-register">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"style="background:#1b355e; padding:2%; border-radius:2%;">
                                        <div>
                                            <h4 style="color:#ffffff;">Sign up to start your campaign:</h6>
                                        </div>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:TextBox ID="FName" placeholder="First Name" Width="100%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:TextBox ID="LName" placeholder="Last Name" Width="100%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:TextBox ID="CustEmail" type="email" placeholder="E-Mail" Width="100%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Source" runat="server" Visible="False" ReadOnly="True">10 Asset Download</asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" OnClientClick="return ValidateForm();" OnClick="submit_Click1" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

THE CS Code is as follows:

```
 using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.UI;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Data.SqlClient;
   using System.Configuration;

   public partial class DownloadLP : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void submit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into LPSUtbl values(@FName, @LName, @CustEmail, @Source)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FName", FName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LName", LName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustEmail", CustEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Source", Source.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "User registered successfully";

            FName.Text = "";
            LName.Text = "";
            CustEmail.Text = "";
            FName.Focus();
        }
    }

   }
```

I have read about a __PostBack function, but wasn't sure how this 100% worked with the JavaScript. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Best, John

Comment: What do you want to achieve and what is happening if you use your code?

Comment: I am trying to use JS to do a quick easy validation of the the three fields. Once validated, it will upload the values to a localDB

Comment: And what is happening if you submit your form without filling in the controls?

Comment: It triggers the posting of the fields, thus resulting in blank submissions

Comment: Can you verify you are getting the reference of your controls correctly and they are not `undefined`?

Comment: They are not undefined and the solution builds without errors

Comment: Obviously solution will build because JavaScript is never compiled when you build the solution. It will throw the errors in your browser console. Just see the browser console if there are errors.

Comment: The browser console has 1 error for the favicon as I didn't link it to the proper end point, but otherwise there are no errors

Comment: So, now you can log your controls, if the value is undefined it will log undefined. just put this line before the if conditions: `console.log(fname);`

Comment: Why not use validation controls and save yourself this bother?

Answer (score 0):

can I first suggest that you place all your javascript in a separate JS file and all your CSS code in a separate CSS file. Further more You will be a happier developer if you place your database calls in a separate data layer class.

For your immediate issue I'd like to recommend that you use JavaScript only and call your logic code using Ajax. If you do this you can manipulate the UI without post backs and do things like validate input using JavaScript, pop up a waiting div or an overlay.

In a web app or web site every time you call a server side event like a button click the request is going to the server which in turn it is going to come back with a response, hence creating a post back.... not a great user experience.